# How to add an attribute to a field a many-to many-field selected entry of a model which is inline in django 1.2?

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models :

```
class POHeader(models.Model):
   number = models.CharField(max_length="5", unique=True)

class Modules(models.Model):
   # this has M:M relationship with the Service model
   name =  models.CharField(max_length="5", unique=True)

class Service(models.Model):
   #id is the key field which is auto generated 
   # apart from other attributes ..
   poheader = models.ForeignKey(POHeader)
   modules = models.ManyToManyField(Module)
```

The Service modelform is inline to the POHeader. Also the modules have a multiple selection as used in admin.py :

```
class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ServiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    modules = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Module.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        """                                                                                                                                                                      
        Service Model                                                                                                                                                            
        """
        model = Service
```

Now the question is, for each of the module selected for each service, I want to add additional details for that module.How can this be achieved? Do these attributes need to be added to service model? How can this be achieved. eg For a poheader 1 entry :

> service1 module1   qty 25
>            module2   qty 27
>
> service2 module7   qty 2

**Here I want to add the additional attribute quantity qty for the module that is selected for the service**

Keeping in mind we are doing the POHeader entry with Service as admin.TabularInline.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to create a model for the many-to-many relationship.

```
class ServiceModule(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Then specify it on the many-to-many relationship.

```
class Service(models.Model):
   poheader = models.ForeignKey(POHeader)
   modules = models.ManyToManyField(Module, through=ServiceModule)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: what solution  you are suggesting is possible, provided the quantity value is common for the multiple modules selected. But this quantity value varies for the different modules selected

Comment: No, that class allows a quantity for each separate module on a service.

Comment: I tried the option, but gives me an exception while trying to display the service model as Inline to POHeader. Exception:ServiceAdmin.fieldsets[0][1]['fields']' can't include the ManyToManyField field 'modules' because 'modules' manually specifies a 'through' model. If I use the M2M attribute without the 'through' it works without showing me the additional attribute in the service inline.

Answer (score 0):

note the difference between this

```
modules = models.ManyToManyField(modules)
```

and this

```
modules = models.ManyToManyField(Modules)
```

also, according to the [1.2 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany), you should add *through*

```
modules = models.ManyToManyField(Module, through=ServiceModule)
```

[this accepted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153026/django-1-2-1-inline-admin-for-many-to-many-fields) may help too

Comment: thank you but I have also tried as per the django documentation, with the correct case of 'Module' and also within the quotes as per the doc for the 'ServiceModule'. It didn't work, gave me the error mentioned below.

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3162027/912450 ? You can use 2 foreginkey fields in the middle table instead of a manytomany field. It may not be the best, like a workaround, but it may fit as a solution for your problem.