# Django Admin Select Objects based on ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

I'm working on building a django app that extends the Mezzanine project.  Mezzanine has a Gallery app (photos).  I'd like to create "portfolio" page that acts as a landing page which has a single image and link to each gallery page.

Each gallery (Gallery) can have multiple images (GalleryImage).  I'd like to via the admin select a gallery, then select an image to be displayed.  However, I can't seem to figure out what to do.

Here's my model:

```
class GalleriesThumb(models.Model):
    relatedlandingpage = models.ForeignKey(LandingPage)
    relatedgallery = models.ForeignKey(Galleries)
    thumb = models.ManyToManyField(GalleryImage)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Galleries(models.Model):
    landingpage = models.ForeignKey(LandingPage)
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    galleries = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
class LandingPage(models.Model):

    gallerytitle = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

My admin is something like:

```
class GalleryInline(admin.InlineModelAdmin)
    model = Galleries
    model = GalleriesThumb
    list_display = galleries
    list_display = thumb

class LangingPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('gallerytitle')
        })
    inlines = [GalleryInline,]
```

I realized that this won't do what i want, but how do I get the list_display on the the images that are related to Galleries. I'm pretty sure it needs to be a method, or am I taking a completing wrong approach if the selections that are made will be defining the content on the page. (I realize that I'm also missing my fields to store the selection in.)

I'm sorry if this a dumb question, but this my first real world attempt an app.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will resolve your problem

[Django 1.2.1 Inline Admin for Many To Many Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153026/django-1-2-1-inline-admin-for-many-to-many-fields/3162027#3162027)

```
class GalleryInline(admin.InlineModelAdmin)
    model = Galleries.galleries.through
```